# How to create a universal labeling rule for areas using different projections

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, labeling

I want to create a universal map style for osm water areas. The data can be in different projections like EPSG:4326 or a metric projection.
To avoid reprojecting them all the time as well as too many labels I need a universal rule to manage this issue. The key is to label only large water areas. Unfortunately this only works in a metric projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using different cases:

```
CASE 

WHEN  layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs_definition') LIKE '%+units=m%' 
THEN
Case When $area > 2000000
Then  "name" 
End

When  layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs_definition') Not LIKE '%+units=m%'
Then
Case When  area(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:3395'))  > 2000000
Then "name"
End

Else
Case When num_points($geometry) > 1000 
Then "name"
End

END
```

First case: if the layer is in a metric projection the expression $area (=m²) is used. Therefore we search for the words "+units=m" in the layer definition. Second case: If the layer uses a non metric projection the layer gets transformed to a metric projection (EPSG:3395) (set this as you like) and the area calculated by using the same expression as before. This can be done with every projection. Third case (most likely never be used, just in case): Only geometries with a minimum of numpoints gets labled.

The code needs to be placed in "label with" field:
[image: screenshot example]